# enum throwing a Identifier expected error

Tags: c#, enums, vb6

Been working through the migration of a VB6 application to C#, we used a conversion tool to migrate the code.  But we are getting a odd error in the enum statement which did not get flagged by the conversion tool.

The code which is having issues is:

```
public enum EncAlgorithm
    {
        DES = ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT | ALG_TYPE_BLOCK | ALG_SID_DES, 
        3DES = ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT | ALG_TYPE_BLOCK | ALG_SID_3DES,
        RC2 = ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT | ALG_TYPE_BLOCK | ALG_SID_RC2,
        RC4 = ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT | ALG_TYPE_STREAM | ALG_SID_RC4
    }
```

The error is flagged after the comma on the first row within the enum constants.  If I comment out the constant 3DES the application will build and the error resolves. I can not however do this as this enum block is used in the licensing of the application.

Comment: You can't start an identifier with a number in C#.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case, still puzzled on why VBUC did not flag this and repair it. Thank you.